# How to delete rows in MySQL, but force the numbering of all next rows to the number of my last id?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 1000 rows.

I need to delete rows from 5 to 1000, so the first 4 remain intact and eveythin after 4 is deleted.

However if I write something like:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id > 4
```

the numbering of the next record after INSERT is 1001, which I do not want.

How to delete rows, but force the numbering of all next rows to the number of my last id?

P.S. I can not use ALTER TABLE to drop all the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your id is in auto increment... What are you using in inserting the next record?PHP? or just the mysql query editor?

Comment: phpmyadmin (mysql query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can you do this?


ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=5
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be working ;). Full statement for beginners like me: DELETE FROM users WHERE uid > 4; ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;

Answer (score 0):

If your id - auto_increment field you need to use ALTER TABLE to change it's value...

But if it's impossible you can try not to delete rows but to set there value to NULL or "" or 0 and then just to update there value
not INSERT but UPDATE ... WHERE id = 5

Answer (score 0):

Think the table is in `auto_increment` . If you cant `ALTER TABLE` you need to manualy give the id in each query, something like

```
 INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table), value);
```

(see comment vis-a-vis lock table)

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not a thread-safe suggestion. If he gets two people pull data at the wrong time, BOOM! Two ID=4.

Comment: But I think the concurrent access anomalies will be handled by MySQL itself and we dont need to do explicitly do anything to prevent it. But in case you are concerned about it, then you can try [Lock Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: Had to edit the answer to remove the down-tick. `(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table)` is generally considered mucho taboo.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL? You don't. AUTO_INCREMENT never... decrements unless you call ALTER TABLE. Have you considered use of a trigger DELETE, however?

(You may need to debug this)

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER DELETE ON theTableInQuestion
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1 < 5 THEN
       ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=5
    END IF;
  END;
|
```

Comment: I have a table users (drupal db) but this CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER DELETE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1 < 5 THEN
       ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=5
    END IF;
  END;
| gives me error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1 &lt; 5 THEN ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ' at line 3

Comment: @marian Where are you running that?

Comment: I am running it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Anyway, the solution from Brian Patterson is working so nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'table_name', RESEED, new_reseed_value )  ==> Works with MS-SQL

#### whereas

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 5 ==> Works with MySQL